# MySQL filter by time issue

Tags: mysql

I need to filter records by time only, so I'm applying this query to MySQL

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE TIME(created_at) >= '07:00:00' AND TIME(created_at) <= '06:59:59';
```

This should filter all records between 24 hours, but no output, however if I change time like below query it works perfectly

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE TIME(created_at) >= '00:00:00' AND TIME(created_at) <= '23:59:59';
```

I've tried to get difference between two given time slots and I'm getting result like this

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF('00:00:00','23:59:59');
```

gives me -23:59:59 hours of difference in total

while

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF('07:00:00','06:59:59');
```

gives me just 00:00:01, but I suppose it should be -23:59:59 like above

What's the better way to fix this simple problem!?

Comment: A single time value will never be both after 7:00 and before 6:59:59. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has a day crossing, so solution would be something like this

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ((TIME(created_at) >= '07:00:00' AND TIME(created_at) <= '23:59:59') OR (TIME(created_at) >= '00:00:00' AND TIME(created_at) <= '06:59:59'));
```